# Retrieving nested JSON data - Ext JS

Tags: json, extjs

Let's start off with my store:

```
var newstore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id', 'table_name', 'name', 'description']
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory'
    }               
});
```

I have some example data here, which comes from a dynamic json response:

```
{
   "elements":[
      {
         "element":{
            "name":"Element Name", <---- This is the value I need** 
            "id":"Element ID",
            "attributes":[
               {
                  "attrname":"id",
                  "attrvalue":"This is the ID"
               },
               {
                  "attrname":"name",
                  "attrvalue":"This is the name"
               },
               {
                  "attrname":"description",
                  "attrvalue":"This is the description"
               },
               {
                  "attrname":"table_name",
                  "attrvalue":"This is the table"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
```

And I decode my json here, which places it neatly into my store:

```
for( var i=0; i < decoded.elements.length; i++ ) {
    var element = decoded.elements[ i ].element;
    var element_name = element.name; <---- THIS retrieves that value I need
    var model = {};  
// loop over attributes
for( var x=0; x < element.attributes.length; x++ ) {
    var attribute = element.attributes[ x ];
    model[ attribute.attrname ] = attribute.attrvalue;
}
    // implicitly cast data as Model
    newstore.add( model ); 
}
```

And lastly, my grid - `ResponseList.js`:

```
var grid = Ext.define('MyApp.view.ResponseList' ,{
    initComponent: function(columns) {
    //config
        this.columns = [ 
            {header: 'Element Name', dataIndex: 'What goes here ???'},
            {header: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id'},
            {header: 'View Name', dataIndex: 'name'}, 
            {header: 'Description', dataIndex: 'description'},
            {header: 'Table Name', dataIndex: 'table_name'}, 
            etc...
```

My question is, how do I place that first **name** value, ***Element Name*** into the first row of my grid? The name **name** is already taken for the `attributes.attrname` field, so I'm not sure how to proceed. Everything except Element Name displays just fine.

[Edit]: This is how I want my grid to look:
[image]

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your fields in the `store` or in a `model` you can specify `mapping` which allows for nested json data:

```
var model = Ext.define('myModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [{
                name: 'id',
                mapping: 'element.id',
                type: 'auto'
            }],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'elements',
                    successProperty: ''
                }
            }
        });
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: model,
            autoLoad: true,
            listeners: {
                load: function() {
                    console.log(store);
                }
            }
        });
        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
            store:store,
            columns: {
                defaults: {},
                items: [{
                    header: "Id",
                    dataIndex: "id",
                    hidden: false
                }]
            }
        });
```

Here is a [fiddle demonstrating working code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/406).

Comment: This code works great but it seems to accomplish getting the element.name and element.id, but now I can't seem to return any of the attributes!

Comment: @ClayBanks I'm not positive exactly what you are looking to do with the attributes since there is more than one in an array.  However, if you are looking to aggregate information into a column then `convert` should work here's a [fiddle for example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/40t).  Otherwise if you want the data in another store then you will want to utilize the `hasMany` property of the store.

Comment: I've figured out exactly what I need to do and your code is very helpful. The only thing I need to know now is how to read my JSON data from my ajax response/define it in the 'model', rather than your predefined data.json.

Comment: @ClayBanks that proxy in the example should be pretty close to what is required for an actual web service.  You should just need to change the url to match the request.  If there are parameters required than `extraParams` needs to be included too.  Here is a [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/weeksdev/8149579/raw/b737a6377d04dec7a6cb4b81ff729f5867857c78/Model.js) i created that i usually use for my models.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the renderer on the grid to get the value you actually need.

```
{header: 'Element Name', dataIndex: 'What goes here ???',
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView){
        return record.someAttribute;
    }
},
```

I'm not sure of the structure of your record, but I think you can guess how to go on from here.

Also, I don't think all that manual decoding is necessary, I can't figure out how you want your grid to look, but if you post a sketch of it or something maybe we can make all that decoding look cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback lascort, I was heading in the direction of renderer. I've included an image of how I want my grid to display.